# Where did enableLogging go with the new Ember router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How do you log route transitions with the new router (1.0.0-pre.4+)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [1bf0df4](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/1bf0df4c95512dd42687a9b2b5ca3936a11aa09a) you can use

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

Note that this is on the Application, not the Router.

(Thanks to @wildchild in [#1673](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1673#issuecomment-11933602) for the pointer.)